# I have taken an image and made it into my gamepiece put on a canvas, but won't rotate properly

Tags: javascript

I have taken an image and made it into my gamepiece put on a canvas, but I cannot get it to rotate properly. I apologize if my code is not very organized just got a little bit hurried. The problem will lie in the component function. Thank you for your help!

```
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "character.png", 300, 300, "image");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas")
    , start: function () {
        this.canvas.width = 640;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    }
    , stop: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    , clear: function () {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function () {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (type == "image") {

            ctx.save();
            ctx.rotate(this.angle);
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.restore();
        } else {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);

            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        }


    }


    this.newPos = function () {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }

    this.hitBottom = function () {
        var bottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - 20;
        if (this.y > bottom) {
            this.y = this.y - 2.5;
        }
    }

    this.hitTop = function () {

        if (this.y < 20) {
            this.y = this.y + 2.5;
        }
    }

    this.hitLeft = function () {

        if (this.x < 20) {
            this.x = this.x + 2.5;
        }
    }

    this.hitRight = function () {
        var side = myGameArea.canvas.width - 20;
        if (this.x > side) {
            this.x = this.x - 2.5;
        }
    }


}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {
        myGamePiece.moveAngle = -2.5;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {
        myGamePiece.moveAngle = 2.5;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {
        myGamePiece.speed = 2.5;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {
        myGamePiece.speed = -1;
    }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    myGamePiece.hitBottom();
    myGamePiece.hitTop();
    myGamePiece.hitLeft();
    myGamePiece.hitRight();
}
```

Comment: without the save and restore. the object starts looping out of control when the left and right keys are pressed (37, 39)